# Write failed: Broken pipe

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, rhel, superuser

i was accessing a vm from a server ip . today i changed that vm ip to a different ip.but while restarting network it showed 
Shutting down interface eth0:  Write failed: Broken pipe
 after that i am not able to access the old ip as well as the new ip i assigned.i think it shutted down the eth0 interface . so i am not able to access.so how to reset that vm network configuration now from server ip??? i am not able to ssh now to that vm from server as well .

note: i ahve a server ip.i am doing ssh to that ip first.then i was doing ssh to a vm ip. i was not able to access directly the vm from outside. so i was configuring that vm to a new ip for outbound access.

Comment: this should be asked on superuser rather than here. does your vm respond to ping?

Comment: no..showing route not available in ping,

Comment: so you should  fix your network settings first. ask your VM provider to attach (virtual) KVM and use one to deal with network misconfiguration

Comment: can u please explain the steps how to fix using kvm? ..virt-manager is already attached in server

Comment: what do **ifconfig**  and **netstat -nr** say?